# spring mvc Always JSON repsonse

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to learn Spring MVC and i'm stuck at this program behaving weirdly can any one please help.

```
 @Controller  
 public class GreetingController {
 @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", consumes={"application/json", "application/xml"},produces = {"application/json","application/xml"}, headers = "Content-type=*/*")
 public @ResponseBody Greeting greeting(
        @RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="I'm default") String name) {
    Greeting obj =  new Greeting("1",name);
    Address address = new Address("CA, US");
    obj.setAddress(address);
    return obj;
   }
 }
```

Greeting and Address are just POJO's.
here is the output from 'curl'  i.e irrespective of Content-type output is in JSON format.

```
curl --header "Content-type: application/xml" http://host.com:8080/javamvc/greeting

{"id":1,"content":"Hello, I'm default!","address":{"addr":"CA, US"}}  

curl --header "Content-type: application/json" http://host.com:8080/javamvc/greeting

{"id":1,"content":"Hello, I'm default!","address":{"addr":"CA, US"}}
```

and then when i use 'RestClient' from mozilla i get output as xml always as  irrespective of my `Content-type=application/json` or `Content-type=application/xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><greeting><id>1</id><content>Hello, I'm default!</content><address><addr>CA, US</addr></address></greeting>
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

In your curl requests, you are specifying the `Content-Type` of the request body, not the content type you are expecting in the response body.

For that, you need to specify [the `Accept` header.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Spring is always producing `application/json`, because it's the first in the list of `produces` values.

You'll have to be more specific about what you are doing with Mozilla, but it seems like it's requesting with the `Accept` header being `application/xml`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Sotirios, now when i give Accept=application/xml i get a Status Code: 406 Not Acceptable.
i tried removing produces from RequestMapping did not help.  Also is produces and consumes compulsory ?

Comment: @shreyasKN No, `produces` and `consumes` are just hints to restrict your `@RequestMapping`. In your case, you need the `produces` to distinguish your mappings, otherwise they'd be the same. As for the 406 status code, I recommend you turn your log level to DEBUG and see what Spring says.

Comment: Got it, i had to configure Jackson http message converter in dispatcher servlet and it works fine for both based on accept type.